# IE pop up window is not re-sizable

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, vaadin

This is a pdf file opened in a pop up window. Chrome and FF work fine (obviously). But the window on EE (10 and 9) is not re-sizable. I read some posts about fixing non-resizable window problems here. They recommend putting a parameter "resizable" in window.open; but I don't use window.open in my code. The code for opening the pdf file in a new window is something this

```
Link pdfLink = new Link("Printable version", createFormLink(url,
                        member.getId().toString(), answers.get(0).getVisitorId(), surveyId, "review.pdf"),
                        "_blank", 500, 400, Link.TARGET_BORDER_NONE);
```

Its the link class from com.vaadin.ui
https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Link.html

I went through the api and couldn't find any parameter that allow IE window to be re-sizable . any help and tips are appreciated

[image]

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517357/com-vaadin-ui-link-class-cannot-re-size-ie-window-when-opening-pdf-file

Comment: 2 including this one. and i assume u dont know how to answer both.

Comment: What ever is wrong with your original question, you should edit it instead of deleting and posting a new question.

Comment: What happens if you change the `Link.TARGET_BORDER_NONE` to `Link.TARGET_BORDER_DEFAULT`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Link` component doesn't allow you to specify parameters like `resizable`. `BrowserWindowOpener` does. Use it like this:

```
Button pdfLink = new Button("Printable version");
pdfLink.addStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);

BrowserWindowOpener windowOpener = new BrowserWindowOpener(createFormLink(...));
windowOpener.setFeatures("width=500,height=400,resizable=yes");
windowOpener.extend(pdfLink);
```